# How to avoid the repeated values in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, checkboxlist

I have a `TextBox`, `Button` and `CheckBoxList`. If I click the checkbox and click the `Button` the value is displayed in `TextBox`. My `TextBox` is `Autocomplete` `TextBox`. if I select the value  from auto complete that value in the `CheckBoxList` is removed. 
Here is my code:

```
     public void ListBox()
       {
            lstCheckBoxList.DataSource = s.sqlconn("select CityName from City");
            lstCheckBoxList.DataValueField = "CityName";
            lstCheckBoxList.DataBind();
       }

    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ListBox();

         foreach (ListItem li in lstCheckBoxList.Items)
         {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                txtPracticeGroup.Text+= li.Text+ ";  ";
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that removes the selected items form the checkboxlist ? Or is your question how to do that?? (It should be done by removing it from the datasource and then maybe rebinding)

Comment: OK, I have added the missing tag. Do you understand my first comment?